# Autoincrement numeric variable in PHP on Refresh

Tags: php

How do I use PHP to auto-increment a numeric variable on page refresh?

Foe example, for `$i=10` there is an output of this:

> Page has been viewed `<?php $i = 10; echo $i;?>` times.

Now I want to increment `$i` when page refreshes so if user loads page 5 times, the number will increase by 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to store its state somewhere, perhaps in the `$_SESSION`.

```
session_start();

$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;

echo ++$i;

$_SESSION['i'] = $i;
```

Comment: this is my code, but it doesn't work.<h4>views<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['i']=100;
$i = isset($_SESSION['i']) ? $_SESSION['i'] : 0;

echo ++$i;

$_SESSION['i'] = $i;

?></h4>

Comment: @enjoylie: You must call `session_start()` before any response body.

Comment: when i refresh the page, the unmber can't auo-increment one?

Comment: now, i put the <?php session_start();> code in my head.php before <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-......and put the rest code in my main.php. but it still doesn't work. how to correct it. thank you

Comment: @enjoylife - take this out `$_SESSION['i']=100`, otherwise you are resetting the session value every time instead of incrementing it.

Comment: Andrew Heath,but i want to give it a default value 100. how do i do?

Comment: @enjoylife Change the `0` in my example to `100`.

Comment: @alex PS - I had no idea `isset()` could be used like that. Pretty cool! +1

Answer (score 3):

you need to store the counter somewhere like a file, database, cookie or session variable.

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['visits']))
        $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;
    $visits = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;
    setcookie('visits', $visits, time()+3600*24*365);
?>

<?php
    if ($visits > 1) {
        echo("This is visit number $visits.");
    } else { // First visit
        echo('Welcome to my Website! Click here for a tour!');
    }
?>
```

Comment: if i want to store the counter in cookie or session variable. how should i do? is there a tutorial about this  thank you.

Comment: Cliff,when i refresh the page, why the number can't auo-increment one?thank you

Answer (score 1):

if it's for the same user session, use a session

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
$_SESSION['counter']++;
```

otherwise, if you want the same count for all users, use database

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with the help of cookies

$cookieName = 'count';
$count = isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName]) ? $_COOKIE[$cookieName] : '';

$newCount = $count+1;
setcookie($cookieName,$newCount);

**$count will return back the updated value**